# How do you update rubygems using rvm and ree?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

How do you update rubygems under rvm when ree is your default vm (on Snow Leopard)? I am doing:

```
$ rvm ree gem update --system
```

This results in things looking like everything went fine:

```
Updating RubyGems
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.3.7
Updating RubyGems to 1.3.7
Installing RubyGems 1.3.7
RubyGems 1.3.7 installed

[...]

RubyGems installed the following executables:
        /Users/douglassellers/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/gem
```

but when I run gem --version it still says 1.3.5.  Doing a which gem points at ree version of gem.

Anyone know how to get rubygems to update with RVM?

Comment: did you verify that ree is the current rvm ruby selected? e.g. `rvm use ree`  then `gem --version`.  I know it sounds dumb, but a mistake i've run into before :-(

Comment: I have verified this.  The strangest thing is that ruby gems seems to think it is updating the correct file.  It says updating ~/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/gem and when I do "which gem" it points at ~/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/gem.  So there must be another version of gem in the require path?  I can't see one though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem, I think, is the initial command (or what you expect that command to do):

```
$ rvm ree gem update --system
```

That tells rvm to pass the `gem update --system` to the `gem` under `ree`, but it doesn't switch you to that particular Ruby interpreter. You continue using whatever interpreter you have set in that shell (whether by default or because you switched manually earlier in the shell session).

As an example, my default interpreter is Ruby 1.9.2. If I pass this command: `rvm 1.9.1 gem install pony`, then the Pony gem is installed for Ruby 1.9.1. However, I'm *still using* Ruby 1.9.2 after that installation is finished. If I enter `irb` and try `require 'pony'`, I get a load error. If I run `rvm 1.9.1` and then enter `irb`, Pony is installed and loads fine.

So as Brian says in his comment to your post, you could switch manually with `rvm use ree`. Alternatively, you could switch your initial command to this:

```
$ rvm ree
$ gem update --system
$ gem --version
```

Comment: This produces the same results as in the original question.  Everything says that it is updating, and gem says that it updated the correct file but when you run gem --version it still says the older version.  When I run "which gem" it points to the same file that rubygems just reported that it updated.

Comment: Please note that `rvm gem ...` was removed, try `gem update --system` or `rvm all do gem update --system` instead. ( see: ['rvm usage'](http://rvm.io/rvm/cli) )

Answer (score 36):

Now you can just do :

```
rvm rubygems latest
```

Or you can define which rubygems you really want. https://rvm.io/rubies/rubygems/

Answer (score 2):

rvm suggested me to use something like this:

```
rvm ruby-1.9.3-p327@mygemset do gem update --system
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an unusual problem.
If it is not yet resolved, consider using

```
rvm --default use ree
which ruby
which gem
```

this should show you if you are in the right version.
install gems either using rvm or directly.